No puedo mostrar el valor selecionado de un select cuando se carga desde la base de datos
Tengo el siguiente codigo


<select class="form-control col-sm-4" style="font-size:10px;" style="width:100px;"  id="Codigo_AreaRegistro" name="Codigo_AreaRegistro" required >
<option style="font-size:12px;" style="width:100px;" value="0"  selected="selected" >Seleccione una opción por Favor:</option>
<?php include './include/combos_selectores/cargarBoxAreasRegistro.php';?> 
</select>



Este código me permite mostrar un select en el formulario de captura, haciendo una llamada asi:


<label for="Codigo_AreaRegistro" class="form-label text-center fw-bold titulo_opcion">Direcci&oacute;n / Area</label>
                                <?php include "cargarAreasRegistro.php";?>  
                                <div id="validation_Codigo_AreaRegistro" class="invalid-feedback"> 
                                    Por favor Seleccione una opci&oacute;n.
                                </div>



Esto hace que se ejecute una consulta y posteriormente muestre el combo select en el HTML,y al guardar el formulario, esta se almacena en la base de datos.   Ahora lo que quiero es que cuando entro al formulario de editar me muestre el selector con el valor precargado de la base de datos,  ya intente con un input hidden colocando la variable que trae el valor desde la base de datos en el value y nada...


<input type="hidden" name="Codigo_AreaRegistro "  id="Codigo_AreaRegistro" value="<?=$codigo_Area_EditarResguardo?>"> 
                                <label for="Codigo_AreaRegistro" class="form-label text-center fw-bold titulo_opcion">Direcci&oacute;n / Area</label>
                                <?php include "cargarAreasRegistro.php";?>  
                                <div id="validation_Codigo_AreaRegistro" class="invalid-feedback"> 
                                    Por favor Seleccione una opci&oacute;n.
                                </div>



incluso renombre el archivo y en el value en lugar de cero, coloque la variable que trae el valor, en el explorador si me muestra el valor, pero no cambia el select, sigue mostrándome el primer elemento de la lista que es "seleccione una opción"
Alguna idea de como resolver este detalle,   se agradece de antemano.  Saludos

Muéstranos como generas los option y el input hidden en el archivo ./include/combos_selectores/cargarBoxAreasRegistro.php, pues es bastante sencillo de solucionar desde PHP, tan solo agregando selected a los atributos del option que recuperas de la base de datos

Tu archivo cargarBoxAreasRegistro.php devuelve una serie de option. Como dices que es el mismo archivo que utilizas tanto en el "nuevo" como en el "editar". Lo más seguro es que no contemplas el uso de selected
Un elemento HTML select toma el primer option a menos que alguno tenga el atributo selected, en cuyo caso tomará el último de ellos.
El problema, es que tienes demasiado acopladas la capa de presentación con la capa de datos. El script en cargarBoxAreasRegistro.php debería retornarte una lista de objetos, no imprimir directamente options. Luego tu recorres la lista en la capa de presentación y muestras esos datos como tú quieras, en este caso agregando selected cuando corresponda. Esta sería la solución usando solo PHP
Lastimosamente, el select debe ser el más nefasto y arcaico de los elementos de formularios. En un mundo ideal deberías poder setear el value y ese ser el valor por defecto (como lo hacen todas las otras tecnologías). Este comportamiento puedes emularlo con un poco de javascript:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => 
   document.querySelectorAll("select")
           .forEach(s => s.getAttribute("value") ? s.value = s.getAttribute("value") : null));

Este código toma el atributo value de los <select> y al cargar el dom, lo establece como su valor predeterminado
Entonces en tu PHP, solo debes:
<label for="Codigo_AreaRegistro" class="form-label text-center fw-bold titulo_opcion">Direcci&oacute;n / Area</label>

<?php /*  ↓ Agregas el value */ ?>
<select value="<?=$codigo_Area_EditarResguardo?>" class="form-control col-sm-4" style="font-size:10px;" style="width:100px;"  id="Codigo_AreaRegistro" name="Codigo_AreaRegistro" required >
    <?php include './include/combos_selectores/cargarBoxAreasRegistro.php';?> 
</select> 
<div id="validation_Codigo_AreaRegistro" class="invalid-feedback"> 
    Por favor Seleccione una opci&oacute;n.
</div>


Gracias por el aporte,   precisamente al despertar pense que podria usar jquery , leer el valor de un imput oculto,  y utilizando ajax "recargar" el select con el valor que viene de la consulta y esto haria que se muestre en el select la opcion señalada.  Pero primero checo lo que me indicas, creo que es mas sencillo.  Saludos
